# ListItem Avatar Not Displaying

Tags: react-native, listviewitem, react-native-flatlist

As part of a `FlatList`, I render each `ListItem` (from the `react-native-elements` library) where I try to display an avatar (icon) from a url to a photo:

```
  <ListItem
     avatar={{ source: { uri: item.icon } }} 
   />
```

All the other props display fine but on the left side of each cell I just get a grey box. I've logged the value of `item.icon` and it points to a valid photo. Do I need to download the photo and then provide a local link to it?

How can I get the photo to show up as the cell's avatar?

Comment: are you using any library or ListItem is your custom component, if it is a custom component please post its code for better understanding

Comment: It is from `react-native-elements`

Comment: Try `avatar={{ uri: item.icon }}`

Comment: That did the trick! Do you know what the diff is between `avatar` and `leftAvatar`?

Comment: `leftAvatar` is in beta version and `avatar` is in stable version as per the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong object for the image avatar.

### Stable Version

**Either**

```
avatar={{ uri: item.icon }}
```

**OR**

```
avatar={<Avatar
           rounded
           source={{uri: item.icon}}
           title={'Sample Title'}
       />}
```

### Beta Version

```
leftAvatar={{ source: { uri: item.icon } }}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to react-native-elements they have leftAvatar and no just avatar

```
<ListItem
        key={i}
        leftAvatar={{ source: { uri: l.avatar_url } }}
        title={l.name}
        subtitle={l.subtitle}
      />
```

Comment: just to test if it is getting your props try adding this
rounded: true
in your leftAvatar object

Comment: When I use `leftAvatar=` I get nothing but when I use `avatar=` I get a grey box without rounded corners.

Comment: For me leftAvatar works with local image, and get grey box with external url

Comment: Works for me in expo web view, but on my mobile device, I get a grey round avatar with no image. Tried calling the image both locally and from the web.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to customize my leftAvatar with icons (react-native-elements / flatlist)

```html
 leftAvatar={{
        icon: { name: item.icon, type: "ionicon", color: "black" },
        size: "large",
        overlayContainerStyle: { backgroundColor: "white" }
      }}
```