# React-Native -Elements Avatar not rendering and showing only gray background even though the image path is correct

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, create-react-native-app

I am trying to render the avatar in my listItem in my React_Native Application but the image is not rendering even though my image URI path is correct and it's only giving the gray background.

Here is my code

```
<View>
      {props.dishes.map((l, i) => (
        <ListItem key={i} bottomDivider>
          <Avatar rounded source={{ uri: l.image }} />
          <ListItem.Content>
            <ListItem.Title>{l.name}</ListItem.Title>
            <ListItem.Subtitle>{l.description}</ListItem.Subtitle>
          </ListItem.Content>
        </ListItem>
      ))}
    </View>
```

Here is the image of what I am getting

[image]

I want the images to be rendered there but it's showing only a grey background. I also tried putting the URI of online images but it's giving the same result.

I also followed the solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53494674/listitem-avatar-not-displaying) but it is not working.

I also passed the online uri to check if my path uri is incorrect but it the same result

```
<Avatar
     source={{
              uri:"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg",        
            }}
          />
```

Comment: What does `console.log(l.image)` show?

Comment: image path images/uthappizza.png
images/zucchipakoda.png
images/vadonut.png
images/elaicheesecake.png

Comment: Pass the style object in avatar and set height and width and you see the image

Comment: @MayankPandeyz it just increasing the grey background size

Comment: In that case you are not getting the image resource on the given url, please check

Comment: The online uri that you passed "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg? doesn't work hence you don't see the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the issue as passing the path of the image like this was not working
Bypassing an image path like this was rendering only grey background.

```
<Avatar rounded source={{ uri: "./images/uthappizza.png"}} />
```

This is how I passed the image path and its rendering properly by using require()

```
<Avatar rounded source={require("./images/uthappizza.png")} />
```

Comment: That worked for me, using local images, but I still get a gray shade from remote ones.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several ways, until I found a guy who encouraged me to check **emulator connectivity** ... and that was the problem!!

**To solve it**, before running your app, launch emulator with

```
emulator -avd <your-emulator-name> -dns-server 8.8.8.8
```